# Elementary System of Equations Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

We are trying to help our daughter with her math homework and can't seem to find how to do this.

K, E and S volunteer at the hospital. In a week, K volunteers 3 hours more than E does and S volunteers 1 hour less than E. Over 3 weeks, the number of hours K volunteers is equal to the sum of E's and S's volunteer hours in 3 weeks. Complete the table to find out how many hours each person volunteers each weeks.

K - how many volunteer hours per weeK? How many in 3 weeks?
E - how many volunteer hours per weeK? How many in 3 weeks?
S - how many volunteer hours per weeK? How many in 3 weeks?

Comment: 1. Write what you tried. 2. There is no table

Comment: 3. The title doesn't give any useful information.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a couple equations, then solve
$$(1) K=E+3$$ $$(2)S=E-1$$ $$(3)3K=3E+3S$$

Substitute (1) and (2) into (3), where you get
$$3E+9=3E+3E-3$$
Simplify, then you get
$$E=4$$
Plug this into equations (1) and (2), where you get $K=7$ and $S=3$

Answer:

K in 1 week=7; K in 3 weeks=21

E in 1 week=4; E in 3 weeks=12

S in 1 week=3; S in 3 weeks=9

Comment: Thank you but I really stink at this so can you break it down? You lost me at "substitute (1) and (2) into (3)." I do not understand how you got any of the equations under that :/

Comment: I labeled the equations with numbers so I don't have to write them every time. I got the equations from your problem.

Comment: K volunteers 3 hours more than E does translates into $K=E+3$, and S volunteers 1 hour less than E translates into $S=E-1$. Over 3 weeks, the number of hours K volunteers is equal to the sum of E's and S's volunteer hours in 3 weeks translates into $3(K)=3(E+S)$ which simplifies into equation (3) in my answer

Comment: To substitute (1) into (3), replace the $K$ you see in equation (3) with $E+3$, since equation (1) says that $K=E+3$.  Similarly, use (2) to replace $S$ with $E-1$.  You'll get the fourth equation.

Answer (score 3):

We're assuming that each person volunteers the same number of hours every week, so the second datum might just as well say that in one week K volunteers the sum of the number of hours that E and S do. So, putting this together with the first datum, since K volunteers 3 more hours than E, we conclude that S volunteers 3 hours a week. Can you take it from here?